# how to require files in a ruby gem if they depend on each other

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have the following structure:

**lib/billomat.rb**

```
require 'dry-configurable'
require 'httparty'

require 'billomat/version'
require 'billomat/account'

module Billomat
  extend Dry::Configurable

  setting :subdomain
  setting :api_key
end
```

**lib/billomat/base.rb**

```
class Billomat::Base
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "https://#{Billomat.config.subdomain}.billomat.net/api"

  def initialize
    @options = { format: 'json', headers: {
      'X-BillomatApiKey' => Billomat.config.api_key
    } }
  end
end
```

**lib/billomat/account.rb**

```
require_relative 'base'

class Billomat::Account < Billomat::Base
  def info
    puts Billomat.config.subdomain
    self.class.get('/clients/myself', @options)
  end
end
```

If I try and access the console with `bin/console` I get an error:

```
lib/billomat/base.rb:3:in `<class:Base>': undefined method `config' for Billomat:Module (NoMethodError)
```

The gem tries to load account.rb that depends on base.rb that uses `Billomat.config` which at this it is not ready. I tried remove `require 'billomat/account'` from the `billomat.rb` and open the console again. Now, I can actually instantiate `Billomat.config`, but I try to call `Billomat::Account.new.info` I get another error:

```
irb(main):005:0> Billomat::Account
NameError: uninitialized constant Billomat::Account
```

because of course `billomat/account` is not required at this point, so I have to require manually.

Question is: how can I organize the code so I can just call `Billomat.configuire {}` and then call `Billomat::Account.new.info` without having to manually require it when I want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby is a scripting language, it reads and processes lines one by one. Just change the order:

**lib/billomat.rb**

```
require 'dry-configurable'
require 'httparty'

module Billomat
  extend Dry::Configurable

  setting :subdomain
  setting :api_key
end

require 'billomat/version'
require 'billomat/account'
```

Comment: it partially works...but since at the time that ruby loaded, Billomat.config is defined, but it is not filled with configuration information and I get this error: `Failed to open TCP connection to .billomat.net:443`. Account is using an empty version of Billomat.config

Comment: I doubt I follow. This is a completely different issue.

Comment: sorry, can you be more clear? what do you doubt? and it is not a different issue cause if I require `account` *after* call `Billomat.config` it works.

Comment: I do not see any call to `Billomat.config` in your code and I have no idea about how it should be called to get values loaded. If one needs to call it before `require`, call it before `require` explicitly. Right after the module definition.

Comment: the `config` should be called by someone who is using the gem, defining the service's subdomain and API key. After that they can call `Billomat::Account.new.....`

Comment: OK, so the issue is `base_uri` DSL is called on class level, not `require` order at all. You have to find a workaround to call it on initialization, e.g. inside `initialize`: `def initialize; self.class_eval { base_uri ... }`.